# How to have subsubsection without new line

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking

I want to have a term and explained it like in the picture below. I tried using something like

```
\subsubsection*{Foo}
```

but without the new line.

[image]

Comment: Use `\paragraph{Foo}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik although having a 4th level heading without a preceding level 3 section heading can lead to problems later (eg if you change `secnumdepth`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ooh... Indeed, I didn't think of that, as always :/

Answer (score 1):

When declaring headings LaTeX uses the sign of the length argument as a flag to set inline or display style so a simple modification from the definition copied from `article.sty` changes to the run-in format:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{bar}zzzz
\subsection{bar bar}zzzz

\subsubsection*{Foo} zzzzzzzzzzzzzz


% from article.cls
%\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
%                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
%                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
%                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
%

% same with 5th argument -ve with a length suitable for horiz space
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                     {-1em}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\subsubsection*{Foo} zzzzzzzzzzzzzz


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422067/), you can use a slightly friendlier syntax provided by the `titlesec` package with the `runin` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\section{bar}zzzz
\subsection{bar bar}zzzz

\subsubsection*{Foo} zzzzzzzzzzzzzz

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{5pt}{}
\subsubsection*{Foo} zzzzzzzzzzzzzz

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that you want a description list instead:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[wide,itemindent=\labelsep]
\item[Java API for WordNet searching (JAPS)] Má asi nejjednodušší API,
ale pracuje přímo se soubory Wordnetu na disku a je proto velmi pomalý.

\item[Java WordNet interface (JWI)] Má také velmi jednoduché API a~navíc
umožňuje načíst celý Wordnet do paměti, a proto je velmi rychlý. Pro
účely implementace jednoduchých metod sémantické podobnosti je naprosto
idéalní.~[Fin14]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to define terms used in your document, I think you should consider using the `glossaries` package.
It makes easier global references to technical terms.

MWE to illustrate this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopostdot]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short-desc}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{jaws}{name={Java API for WordNet searching},
        short={JAWS},
        description={Mà asi nejjednodussí API\textellipsis{}}
}
\newacronym[description={Má také velmi\textellipsis{}}]{jwi}{JWI}{Java WordNet interface}


\begin{document}

Let’s talk about the \gls{jaws},
also known as
\glsentryshort{jaws}.


\vspace{2\baselineskip}
Then, let’s describe the \gls{jwi}
with some text.

After that, it will be reffered to as \gls{jwi}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Compilation sequence:

```
lualatex test.tex
makeglossaries test
lualatex test.tex
```

More info in the `glossaries` [documentation at CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries).